# Can someone confirm if I am running this generalized linear model in R correctly?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, anova

I'm a grad student and stats beginner just trying to make sure I'm using the right model and using it correctly. I'm using R version 3.5.0. My data look like this:

```
   Nest_ID  Treatment  BCI 
 1     001        NTC 2.18 
 2     001        NTC 2.54 
 3     001        NTC 2.23 
 4     001        NTC 2.33 
 5     001        NTC 2.37 
 6     002        NTC 2.10 
 7     002        NTC 2.61 
 8     002        NTC 2.51 
 9     002        NTC 2.18 
10     002        NTC 2.40 
11     003         A1 2.15 
12     003         A1 2.29 
13     003         A1 2.45 
14     003         A1 1.80 
15     003         A1 2.15
77     004         C1 2.31
78     004         C1 2.21
79     004         C1 2.54
80     004         C1 2.29
81     004         C1 2.38
```

I have multiple BCI data points for each nest and 5 treatment groups. I want to know if there are differences in BCI between the treatment groups, but each BCI corresponds to individuals from the same nest, and each nest received the same treatment. So at first I took the average BCI from each nest to get a single BCI from each nest and ran an ANOVA on it. This seemed to work fine, but a colleague told me I could use glm and it would account for the fact that I have multiple individuals from a nest that received the same treatment. I tried glm in R, and I don't see how it's accounting for the nest being the lowest statistical unit.

```
GLM <- glm(BCI ~ Treatment, data = Data)
```

When I use this formula, my results come back significant when I don't think they should be. They came back not significant when I just took the average BCI from each group. Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Please provide example data as plain text, not images, so other users can easily copy/paste. Also, there is insufficient example data to investigate your issue since the `Treatment`  = NTC in all rows.

Comment: I couldn't get plain text to format correctly. I will add it though, and add data from other treatments

Comment: Someone will fix the formatting for you, if it isn't too long and tedious :)

Comment: Thanks! It was formatted correctly when I typed it but it doesn't come through the same way when I submit it.

Comment: This sounds like a repeated measures design, which I would approach with a mixed-effect model (the fixed effect would be the `Treatment` here, and the random effect the `Nest_ID`). This is to account for a potential `Nest_ID`-specific (batch) effect on `BCI`. `lme4::lmer` would be one way to model the data. Or perhaps with a Bayesian approach a la `rstanarm::stan_lmer`. You should be able to find plenty of tutorials on the net and many relevant posts on StackOverflow and CrossValidated.